# I can't convert data into appropriate format

Tags: excel, vba

I created auto-populating offset function to add data into my list. Now I need to convert the inserted data into the same format as cells above. I reckon there is some shorter code to do this. Mine's not working anyway. The data are scattered all over the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub data_entry()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ItemNumber As String
Dim ItemType As String
Dim Issues As String
Dim InventoryValue As String

ItemNumber = InputBox("Please enter Item Number", "Item Number", "Type here")
ItemType = InputBox("Please enter Item Type", "Item Type", "Type here")
Issues = InputBox("Please enter Number of Issues", "Issues", "Type here")
InventoryValue = InputBox("Please enter Inventory Value", "Inventory Value", "Type here")

Range("A2").Activate

Do

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Loop

ActiveCell.Value = ItemNumber
'ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ItemType
'ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Issues
'ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7).Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = InventoryValue
'ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 8).Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats


End Sub
```

Comment: What you had should almost work. You had `'ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 8).Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats` but I think it should be `'ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 8).Copy
'ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats` Did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will achieve your expected results without Activating a cell and without the Do Loop too, both of which will invariably result in reduced performance:

```
Sub Data_Entry()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'or you could be more explicit and use: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet being used, amend as required.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ItemNumber As String
Dim ItemType As String
Dim Issues As String
Dim InventoryValue As String

ItemNumber = InputBox("Please enter Item Number", "Item Number", "Type here")
ItemType = InputBox("Please enter Item Type", "Item Type", "Type here")
Issues = InputBox("Please enter Number of Issues", "Issues", "Type here")
InventoryValue = InputBox("Please enter Inventory Value", "Inventory Value", "Type here")

NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'find the next free row in Column A

ws.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = ItemNumber
'another way to reference a cell would be: ws.Cells(NextRow, 1).Value = ItemNumber
ws.Range("F" & NextRow).Value = ItemType
ws.Range("H" & NextRow).Value = Issues
ws.Range("I" & NextRow).Value = InventoryValue


ws.Range("A" & NextRow - 1 & ":I" & NextRow - 1).Copy
'Copy above row from Columns A to I
ws.Range("A" & NextRow & ":I" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'paste the formating to new row Columns A to I
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Short and effective. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try :

```
Option Explicit
Sub data_entry()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ItemNumber As String
Dim ItemType As String
Dim Issues As String
Dim InventoryValue As String

ItemNumber = InputBox("Please enter Item Number", "Item Number", "Type here")
ItemType = InputBox("Please enter Item Type", "Item Type", "Type here")
Issues = InputBox("Please enter Number of Issues", "Issues", "Type here")
InventoryValue = InputBox("Please enter Inventory Value", "Inventory Value", "Type here")

Range("A2").Activate

Do

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Loop

ActiveCell.Value = ItemNumber
'ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)).Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("NameSheet").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Sheets("NameSheet").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).PasteSpecial PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ItemType
'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Copy
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)).Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("NameSheet").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Sheets("NameSheet").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).PasteSpecial PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Issues
'ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7).Copy
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7)).Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("NameSheet").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Sheets("NameSheet").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).PasteSpecial PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = InventoryValue
'ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 8).Copy
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 8)).Copy
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Sheets("NameSheet").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Sheets("NameSheet").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).PasteSpecial PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats


End Sub
```